# How to add a designated key to close an application

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a web browser in Visual Basics, and want to asign the "CTRL" key to close down the program. Has anyone got any ideas on how to?

I've tried scouting the web for some code, but unsure where to put it currently as I'm new to this.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub OvalShape1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OvalShape1.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoBack()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OvalShape2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OvalShape2.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoForward()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

That's what I've got at the moment

When I've tried different codes on the internet, it just spits me out an error, and I believe it's because I'm unsure of where to put it.

Comment: `Ctrl` may be confusing. If someone tries to copy something (`CTRL-C`), it will close the application instead. Maybe another combination of keys. What do you think about `ALT-F4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this winforms? If it is, then this should work.

1. Set the `KeyPreview` of the form to `True` from the designer:

   [image]
2. Under the `KeyDown` event of the form, enter this code

   ```
   Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
       If e.KeyCode = Keys.ControlKey Then
           Me.Close()
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply, but I'm abit lost. I've enabled KeyPreview, but what now? http://prntscr.com/ne54nt

Comment: Alright, I've figured out how to do it, but still doesn't close the application